# Unexpected Behaviour ItemsControl Template/ItemTemplate

Tags: xaml, itemscontrol, stackpanel, itemtemplate

I would like to present a summary list side by side, so I created a small ItemsControl to achieve that goal:

```
    <ItemsControl x:Name="GRS">
        <ItemsControl.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <TextBlock Text="Round" FontSize="20" />
                        <TextBlock Text="Food" FontSize="20" />
                        <TextBlock Text="Harvest" FontSize="20" />
                        <TextBlock Text="State" FontSize="20" />
                        <TextBlock Text="Private" FontSize="20" />
                        <TextBlock Text="Value" FontSize="20" />
                        <TextBlock Text="Type" FontSize="20" />
                    </StackPanel>
                    <ItemsPresenter />
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.Template>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border Margin="10" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=RoundNumber}" FontSize="20" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=PlayerAndModusSetting.FoodCost}" FontSize="20" />
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsHarvest}" FontSize="20" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=PlayerAndModusSetting.StateBuildProject}" FontSize="20" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=PlayerAndModusSetting.PrivateBuildProject}" FontSize="20" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value}" FontSize="20" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ShipType}" FontSize="20" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

When I set the ItemsSource & run, the result is the lists orientated vertically instead of horizontally.

[image: Example of wrong behaviour]

As you can see, the first one is side by sidem but after that, it continues downwards, and I can't tell why.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

The parent control of your Item Template is a `StackPanel` - each item is a `StackPanel`, contained within a `StackPanel` - you need to change the container around your `ItemsPresenter` to `WrapPanel` if you want it to tile horizontally.

Example:

```
                </StackPanel>
                <WrapPanel>
                    <ItemsPresenter />
                </WrapPanel>
            </StackPanel>
```

Comment: That's Incorrect. The same behaviour is achieved (just tested it). Also, the stackpanel's orientation was set to horizontal, that means it should expand horizontal and not vertical (which it does for the entire content in ItemTemplate).